# Amazon SES email is not working on localhost

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

I am using following WordPress plugin to send email.

http://coffee2code.com/wp-plugins/configure-smtp/

I have done configuration, which is working fine for server but same configuration is giving following error on localhost.

> An error was encountered while trying to send the test e-mail.
> SMTP Error: Data not accepted.

On localhost, I tested gmail setting with this plugin, which works fine, but error comes with configured using Amazon SES settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, Sender Email address must be same as configured 'From Address' on Amazon.